# How to validate a filename using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

Hi i am writing a regex for filename validation. Combining bits and pieces from different forums but not having the correct test results. Below is the format with the example that i want to achieve

> FORMAT: ABC<1|2>_DEF<6-7digits>_GHI<1|2|3>.xml EXAMPLE:
>   ABC2_DEF1234567_GHI3.xml

and here is the regex defined in Java.

```
private static final String PATTERN = "ABC[1|2|3]+_DEF\\d[0-9]{6,7}+_GHI[1|2|3].xml$";
```

Comment: Why? Let the file system do it. Don't try to second-guess the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should suffice:

`"(?i)abc[12]_def\d{6,7}_ghi[123]\.xml`

Note the use of `?i` flag to match case-insensitively. You may also use the `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` constant.

This regex matches `abc` followed by either a `1` or a `2`, followed by `_def`, followed by 6-7 digits, followed by `_ghi`, followed by a `1`, `2`, or `3`, with the extension `.xml`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UcxtH5/1)

Comment: This is equally good and perfectly surve the purpose. Thumbs up for the case insensitive handling. Thank-you

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you might likely want to design an expression similar to:

```
^ABC[12]_DEF[0-9]{6,7}_GHI[1-3]\.xml$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qFVjgf/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/qFVjgf/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^ABC[12]_DEF[0-9]{6,7}_GHI[1-3]\\.xml$";
final String string = "ABC2_DEF1234567_GHI3.xml\n"
     + "ABC<1|2>_DEF<6-7digits>_GHI<1|2|3>.xml";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]